# Are all Acer Nitro laptops eligible for egpu?

Tags: thunderbolt

Is acer VN7-593G-73HP eligible for egpu?
(Are all Acer Nitro laptops eligible?)

https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/acer+aspire+v+15+nitro+black+edition+gaming+vn7+593g+73hp/?nbb=pla.google_&wt_cc2=911-0001_Hardware_295693&gclid=CPSz5t3r-9QCFdAV0wodTuwDBg

Comment: Why would you need an eGPU for that laptop? It already has a 1060 built in.

Comment: @Mokubai For 1year later

Comment: What about 1 year later? If you think that a 1060 isn't going to manage games in 1 years time then you are either overestimating where games will be by then, or underestimating what a 1060 can do. Sure you're not going to be able to play the latest games at 4K with all the settings at Ultra, but it should be pretty reasonable.  Consoles are the main factor limiting graphical improvements in games these days anyway.

Comment: @Mokubai i dont know which games there will be. 1year refers to future. Someday i will want to use egpu for 4k 60frames ultra setting i think. Aside from this, i want to know the possibility as i also mentioned "Are all Acer Nitro laptops eligible?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, [according to NotebookCheck.net](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-Aspire-V15-Nitro-BE-VN7-593G-7700HQ-GTX-1060-Laptop-Review.207344.0.html) you have a Thunderbolt port on the specific laptop you mention.

Reddit page [DIY eGPU 101: Introduction to eGPU](https://www.reddit.com/r/eGPU/comments/5jpf2x/diy_egpu_101_introduction_to_egpu/) also suggests that having Thunderbolt is a damn good place to start with eGPU but it is by no means a guarantee.

The best answer you're going to get is "maybe" along with "you'll have to try it and tell us."

From that Reddit:

> #### I read all of this, am I ready to order my eGPU? How do I know that it will actually work for my system?
>
> Well, as I wrote above, if you can find someone's worklog/guide with the same Laptop as you and using the same enclosure, then you typically have a good idea of what you need to do. Just follow in their footsteps as accurately as possible. If you're pioneering on a laptop nobody tried before, then you're running the risk of not being able to get it to work. **In general, Thunderbolt is the easiest one to get working**, followed by Expresscard, and finally M.2 and mPCIe. **It is a good idea to make the smallest investment possible, such as getting an adapter/enclosure, a suitable power supple and a placeholder video card (or borrow one, if you can). That way you won't be spending on a video card before you are sure your system is eGPU capable.** Once the simple card works, you can buy the actual eGPU of your dreams. If it doesn't you didn't waste more than you had to in order to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will keep my question as opened in case somebody provides more accrate data (info) which might be based on one's experience.

Comment: @Jackson I'm not too troubled about what you choose to do with your question. I could not find any definitive information beyond "Thunderbolt has the best chance without spending a lot of money and time buying said laptop and a completely redundant eGPU setup for it (due to the power of the dGPU already fitted). " As it is quite powerful already I doubt anyone will care enough to try an eGPU on it for several years. The best information I can find says "if you have Thunderbolt then probably maybe, but you'd have to try it to find out".

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. I just accepted your answer.